# Question regarding singular/plural in amounts

Tags: noun, grammatical-number

I'm a bit confused in determining the usage of plural/singular in amounts, especially when it concerns only 1 amount of something, for example(s):

> Eine Million Deutsche ist/sind nicht zufrieden mit ihrer Arbeit.
>
> Ein Prozent aller Tiere ist/sind vom Aussterben bedroht.
>
> Eine Menge Menschen wurde/wurden gestern Nacht ermordet.
>
> Ein paar Leute ist/sind...

etc.

Which ones would be the correct answers or more frequently used, especially in schools/colleges/universities?

edit:

> mehr/weniger als eine...

Is always plural too right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends! Let me begin from behind.

#### ein paar

The fixed phrase [*ein paar*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein_paar) is synonymous to *einige*. It is composed of the two indefinite pronouns *ein* and [*paar*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/paar#Indefinitpronomen) (*ein* does not refer to the numeral [*ein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Numerale) here). The verb is plural, because the subject *Leute* is:

> - Ein paar Leute sind ...  ⇆  Einige Leute sind ...

#### eine Menge

This is a bit tricky.

If [*Menge*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Menge) refers to the mathematical term (a *set* in English), it is considered as an entity. To specify what the set is about, one could say *eine Menge **von** irgendwas* where *irgendwas* is in dative case. But mathematicians often try to use language economically, and so they use the genitive *eine Menge irgendwas*. Regardless, the numerus depends on how many sets you are talking about:

> - Eine Menge reeller Zahlen wurde ...  ⇆  Eine Menge von reellen Zahlen wurde ...
> - Zwei Mengen reeller Zahlen wurden ...  ⇆  Zwei Mengen von reellen Zahlen wurden ...
>     
>     ...
> - *n* Mengen reeller Zahlen wurden ...  ⇆  *n* Mengen von reellen Zahlen wurden ...

In contrast, when *eine Menge* is used as a synonyme of the indefinite pronoun [*viel*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/viel), then the numerus of the verb depends on that of the noun. Unless a mathematician talks about mathematical sets of people, we therefore have:

> - Eine Menge Menschen wurden ...  ⇆  Viele Menschen wurden ...
> - Eine Menge Holz wurde ...  ⇆  Viel Holz wurde ...

#### eine Million

When *eine Million* is treated as a numeral, then the numerals' rules of the correct numerus apply. Only the numeral *eins* demands the singular; all other numerals demand the plural. Thus, it is:

> - Ein Deutscher ist ...
> - Zwei Deutsche sind ...
>     
>     ...
> - Eine Million Deutsche sind ...
>     
>     ...

#### ein Prozent

Percentages are used to express proportions, more precisely the number of items per one hundred of similar items. Actually, *Prozent* is Latin for *von Hundert*. Therefore, the numerus depends on how many items (of one hundret) you are talking about:

> - Ein Prozent aller Tiere ist ...  ⇆  Ein Tier von hundert Tieren ist ...
> - Zwei Prozent aller Tiere sind ...  ⇆  Zwei Tiere von hundert Tieren sind ...
>     
>     ...
> - Einhundert Prozent aller Tiere sind ...  ⇆  Einhundert Tiere von hundert Tieren sind ...

Comment: *Das ist aber eine Menge Holz.* Nicht *eine Menge Hölzer*. Es kommt darauf an, ob das Substantiv abzählbar gemeint ist oder nicht. Vergleiche auch *ein Häufchen Mensch*.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That was very clear. So it seems to me that "ein paar" and "eine Menge ___" require the plural, when they're just expressing common things people say, such as "ein paar Worte[Nom.]", "eine Menge Worte[Nom.]" (when there is no article or adjective to determine the case) and such, but they act as a single unit that require the singular, when dativ or genitiv is used and the word Menge itself is in singular. And so functions "eine Million" more or less the same, regarding multiple objects (people), (Ein) Prozent works exactly like any other nouns (1=sing >1=plural).

Comment: @Janka You are right. I edited the answer.

Comment: Is that correct? I'm sorry, the amount of words are limited here hahaha

Comment: And also, too add, wie ist es bei "Hälfte/ein Drittel/Viertel.."? Singular, right?

Comment: "... then the numerus of the verb depends on that of the noun." Also das erscheint mir invertierte Logik zu sein. Muss nicht der Numerus des Subtantivs von der Semantik abhängen? Im realen Leben bekommt man ja keine Sätze, in denen ein Wort fehlt, reingereicht, sondern konstruiert den ganzen Satz selbst. Was wäre sonst bei Substantiven, wenn nicht erkennbar wäre, ob sie Singular oder Plural sind, also man statt "Eine Menge Menschen haben für Trump gestimmt" sagte "Eine Menge Wähler hat/haben für Trump gestimmt" (der Wähler/die Wähler)? "Eine Menschenmenge/Menge Menschen raste zum Strand".

Comment: @Björn Friedrich sorry, I forgot to @ you.

Comment: @bbbird Yes, that is (almost) correct. But nitice Janka's comment about _eine Menge Holz_, which I took into account in an edit. Furthermore, the numerus with _ein Halb_, _ein Drittel_, and so on is singular.

Comment: @userunknown Following the logic and the rules that were established here, I think "eine Menge Wähler" and also "eine Menge Menschen" are already in plural. I believe it makes more sense that way. (The same way with eine Menge, ein paar, eine Million).

Comment: @bbbird: Und "Eine Schiffsladung Passagiere betrat das Land." würdest Du ankreiden?

Comment: @userunknown With regards to the established "rule of the thumb" I would say "betraten". I've seen in several other websites/threads that both variations would be correct, but to keep consistent I would use the konjugation for pl here (multiple objects). If you however say eine Schiffladung von Passagieren/der(or even better "erschreckter") Passagiere, I believe "betrat" would be appropriate, because the sentence's subject would be that single unit, instead of signifying multiple people. I'm not that sure though, let's wait and see if B. Friedrich sees this comment, I'm sure he'd know better.

Answer (score -2):

Eine Million Deutsche sind nicht zufrieden mit ihrer Arbeit.

Ein Prozent aller Tiere ist vom Aussterben bedroht. (This one is hard as you have a subject that is grammatically a singular (Prozent) that, however, most likely  means a multitude of people. I'd still go with the grammatical singular.

Eine Menge Menschen wurden gestern Nacht ermordet. To me that implies that a number of people were killed yesterday night and these people were at different places when they were killed.

Eine Menge Menschen wurde gestern Nacht ermordet. Also possible, but here the implication is that they were together (e.g. as protesters) when they were killed. A "bundle" killing.

Ein paar Leute sind...

Comment: These seem to be merely examples with no explanation. Hence I give -1 here